# How to get total weight from cart prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I know how can i get the total weight from order, is like that:

```
$orderWeight = sprintf("%.2f ".Configuration::get('PS_WEIGHT_UNIT'), (float)$order->getTotalWeight());
```

But i try changing `$order` for `$cart` but the result is an error, so how can i get the total weight from cart?

I have this:

```
$products = $this->context->cart->getProducts(true);
        $orderWeight = sprintf("%.2f ".Configuration::get('PS_WEIGHT_UNIT'), (float)$products->getTotalWeight());
        echo $orderWeight;
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function getTotalWeight() on a non-object

Comment: Did you try `$this->context->cart->getTotalWeight();`? Are you using Prestashop 1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cart class contain a method `getTotalWeight()`.

You should be able to get cart weight with this code:

```
$cartWeight = sprintf("%.2f ".Configuration::get('PS_WEIGHT_UNIT'), $this->context->cart->getTotalWeight());
```